# How does History in jQuery Mobile work? (in particular when involving the back button)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, history, back, jsrender

This history thing on jqm is driving me nuts... and every time I think I have the solution, it slips from my grasp.

Here's the thing: I'm developing a dynamically generated content app. The pages are generated from JSON files and rendered using jsRender. They are loaded into the DOM (I'm using a jqm multi-page templating for this) on the first request and, on the following, they are simply called using a changePage pointing to that #id (the model I took inspiration from is this: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html ). Everything works fine but after a while the DOM becomes too crowded and slows down my system (in particular smartphones where I load the app into). The solution is to cancel the page just after it has been left by the user like in this project:
http://roughlybrilliant.com/jsrender_json_apis_and_jquery_mobile

It uses the

```
$.mobile._bindPageRemove
```

instruction. Anyway, instead of using that, my first try was to use the .remove() instruction furnished by jQuery:

```
$("#" + entity.name + "-" + entityId).bind('pagehide', 
     function() {
         $(this).remove();
     });
```

So whenever a page is hidden, it is removed from the DOM. So let's say we'd hit a link in my page to go to another, the starting page is deleted and the new one is loaded. 
Here I have a back button, so when I hit it, it takes me back 1 step to the page I just deleted. Now in my code I have a function that builds the page again and shows it. Just to have the general idea of how my app works.

Now let's say I can go deeper then 1 level in my tree of links: let's say I'm on lvl 2 and go to lvl 3 and then back to 2. In this case, the lvl 2 page does not have the back button, even if in the code I set it to be present.

Here's the template in jsRender:

```
<script id="header-buttons" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="inline" data-backbtn="true">
    <h1>{{:name}}</h1>
    <a href="#root" class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="home">Home</a>
    </div>
</script>
```

I thought it was because the remove instruction (or the $.mobile._bindPageRemove) was also removing the page from the history.. so I changed and used the empty() instruction to just empty the div and then re-populate it with what I needed... with no success. I can go back only 1 level in my tree if I remove the page after I visit it.

My aim is to go around my app loading the pages dynamically and once I leave them, I just want to remove them from the DOM without altering the history, so when I go back and reload the page, I always have the back button available in the page.

So my question(s) is(are): how the history works in jqm? When jqm enhances the page with its code does it add any indication for the back button on which page should it point to? How can I force the page to display the back button and point to the previous element in the history? Is it possible that if I remove something from the DOM it is NOT removed from history too?

Thanks for the help, hope my concern is clear enough...

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm working within a multi-page template...

Answer (score 0):

Set the following command in a separate js file required by the page.

```
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = false;
```

What that does is basically doesn't cache the old pages into the DOM.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I went that way but with no luck. Basically I need the pages to be removed from the dom but stay in the history... that is want I'd like to achieve

Comment: I tested and my history worked fine... Have you thought simply removing ajax and going page to page naturally?

Comment: I cannot remove ajax since it's part of the project. I retrieve json code dynamically when the page is called, render the content using templates with jsRender and then enhance them with jqm. Basically I use the protocol described here: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html if that makes sense..

Comment: Are all your files in a row? ie Home->menu->item every time? or can you get to pages from anywhere? If they are in a row, I'd recommend instead of using browser history, just creating a back button with changepage. If they are from anywhere, I think you're out of luck; that isn't what jquery mobile was coded for.

Comment: Well, that is a nice idea, although I'd like to bookmark the pages I visit, hence I can come from everywhere, possibly visiting any page. In your opinion, can I link the back button to the page I'm leaving? and if that page is not in my domain, simply don't display the back button?

Comment: That would be my personal solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've sorted this out in the way similar to what Jonathan suggested me.

I've created a separate stack where I keep track of the pages I've visited and their URLs. Then, with a helper function, I check this stack and create a button pointing backwards. So if the last entry of the stack is the active page, the second last will be the one I'm pointing to with my back button.

Hope that helps!